# Cached Route is Cleared on Skmaps

Tags: android, caching, routes, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I am trying to save route using SkRouteManager's saveroutetocache, and showing route using loadroutefromcache but actually the route is not being saved so every time I load it from the stored id, it shows the route cannot be calculated.

Is there any way to save the route not just in the current map view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [dedicated chapter](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec042) for route caching/loading in the documentation and also see the implementation in the demo project (you will have to make sure that "provideMultipleMapSupport" is true in the demo project's manifest for the multiple map views code to be active - see [this](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec041) for details)

Comment: When I destroy the application from the application tray, the cached route is also cleared, I want the save the cached route.

Comment: This is not possible - the route cache is not persistent between different application runs